# Problems with arrays of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having an entry level C pointer problem... Let's say I have two strings and I want to print them. What am I misunderstanding in the code below?

```
void print_array(char **array[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while((*array)[i] != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", (*array)[i++]);
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char str1[] = "hello";
    char str2[] = "world";
    char **array = {str1, str2};

    print_array(&array);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

For my code to work I need to access the array like it is in `print_array`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry I should have said the data in array isn't correct. And at runtime it says `Seg. Fault`

Comment: I assume you might want something like `print_array(char** array)` and `char** array = {str1, str2, NULL}; print_array(array);`

Comment: Check the fix here http://ideone.com/a5PZk0

Comment: You know, both your `return`-statements are superfluous... Also, there's no percentage in normalizing a value in a boolean context.

Comment: By the way, no one has given an answer in the `char **array[]` format I needed. I know now that the issue is in the declaration of array in `main()`. When I malloc the array together it works just fine.

Comment: @EricFossum: Why do you need that additional indirection? Doesn'T it just make things more error-prone?

Comment: @JohnKugelman: Added a variant where I went back to your signature for `print_array`

Comment: You just needed to pass a pointer as an array to the function print_array(). Then print elements from the pointer that you have used as an array. So you have a pointer of array and to access it you need to: array[i] or *array++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another take on it (Much more refactoring).

Bugfixes:

- Corrected confusion what should be dereferenced and how in `print_array` (Don't aspire to 3-star-programming, unless you must)
- Added the missing sentinel-0 in to the array passed from `main` to `print_array`

Other changes:

- Removed superfluous `return`-statements (`main` has an implicit `return 0;` at the end)
- Removed superfluous checks for unequality to `0` / `NULL`
- Removed one level of indirection from `print_array`
- Use of `const` in `print_array` where appropriate
- Eliminated counter-variable in `print_array`
- Used a constant compound-literal in `main` (Needs C99)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(const char *const array[]) {
    while(*array)
        printf("%s\n", *array++);
}

int main() {
    print_array((const char*[]){"hello", "world", 0});
}
```

[<kbd>See here on coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05706ada560964f0)

---

Undoing the cleanup steps changing the signature of `print_array`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(char **array[]) {
    for(char** p = *array; *p; p++)
        printf("%s\n", *p);
}

int main() {
    print_array(&(char**){(char*[]){"hello", "world", 0}});
}
```

[<kbd>Live on coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f723b7df190cbc30)

Answer (score 2):

There's one too many `*`'s in `print_array`. It ought to be this:

```
void print_array(char *array[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while(array[i] != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i++]);
    }
}
```

That makes calling it straightforward. Change `char **array` to `char *array[]`. And don't forget to include a `NULL` entry at the end of the array.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char str1[] = "hello";
    char str2[] = "world";
    char *array[] = {str1, str2, NULL};

    print_array(array);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

On the other hand, if you're not supposed to modify `print_array`, then that's annoying. You'll need another variable to hold `array`'s address temporarily.

```
char *array[] = {str1, str2, NULL};
char **p = array;

print_array(&p);
```

That's why I say there's one too many `*`'s in `print_array`.

Answer (score 1):

since you're dealing with arrays, please pass in the number of array members to `print_array`. The code above is UB.

To fix your code:

```
void print_array(char *arr[], int cnt) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char str1[] = "hello";
    char str2[] = "world";
    char *arr[] = {str1, str2};

    print_array(arr, 2);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Being more specific, the original code is UB because it iterates off the end of the array. OP perhaps expected that reading off the end of an array would give `0` or equivalent; of course it doesn't.

Comment: the extra level of indirection was not needed in order to just read the array, but it wasn't a mistake either

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print_array(char *array[]) {
   int i = 0;
   while (array[i] != 0) {
   printf("%s\n", array[i++]);
}
return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char str1[] = "hello";
    char str2[] = "world";
    char *array[] = {str1, str2, 0};

    print_array(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Aniket That's silly. Comparing against 0 is a perfectly fine way of checking for null pointers.

Comment: @Deduplicator it IS 0, but comparing it directly AS 0.. seems odd to me. Eyes hurt

Comment: @Aniket I think you know NULL and 0 means the same thing in C/C++. Eg. if you have a char pointer or pointer something else ptr,  you can do "if (ptr != 0)" or "if (ptr != NULL)" .

Comment: @Aniket there is implicit conversion from *integer constant expression with value 0* to *null pointer*

Comment: @MattMcNabb I just think `NULL` is more readable. Just personal preference I guess.

Comment: @Aniket: Even better readable would be leaving that comparison out entirely. Everything else being equal, I prefer brevity.

Comment: @Deduplicator it's a reasonably common idiom, I don't consider it to be so bad that it needs to be corrected. It can help readability, to make it clear that a pointer comparison is happening.